Median equality test for non-normal distributions
Despite many articles affirm that we can use the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test to compare medians when the assumption of normality is violated, the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test does not compare medians between non-normal distributions:

The Wilcoxon test is sometimes said to test for equality of median, here is a proof that this is not what it does
Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test does not compare medians
The (frequent) interpretation of the Mann-Whitney(-Wilcoxon)  test as a test for median difference, for mean difference, or for location shift (pick yer interpretation) results from the two additional (stringent) assumptions: (i) the distributions of group A and group B have identical shapes, (ii) the distributions of group A and group B have identical variances.

If we cannot use the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test to compare medians of non-normal distributions, which test can we use to test the equality of medians between non-normal distributions (either with different variance or different shape, or both different)?

Quantile regression? There is also the issue that testing for equality is not the usual hypothesis test, but you could apply the two one-sided tests paradigm just as well.

Thanks for your comment...however, I can do the quantile regression (with \tau=0.5 to get the median regression), i.e. rq(x, y, tau=0.5) (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/quantreg/versions/2.0-2/topics/rq)....but then what? I mean, I can get intercept and slope of the regression, but it does not look like a test...or...Am I misinterpreting?

The key to addressing this is to formulate a suitable null and suitable alternative hypothesis, because the null hypothesis "the medians are equal" is far too vague--it's a huge composite hypothesis--which, without being made more precise or without being contrasted to a specific alternative, is almost impossible to test.  One way to make it testable is to suppose the two distributions differ only by an additive shift in the null, for instance. With large datasets you can use asymptotic approximations to the variance of the median.

There already is a test for exactly what you are asking; Mood's median test (see wiki). Now, yes, it can be argued that it does not have great power (it is basically a binomial test, using a $\chi^2$ statistic). But it works.
And of course, you have bootstrap; a bootstrap on the difference of medians, then checking if the CI includes 0, or not. That is the one I would use, if I had to make that analysis. E.g. see this post.
Last, as suggested in a comment, you can use a two one-sided test (TOST) procedure.
All of the above will test the equality of 2 medians, w/o any distributional assumptions.

Oh wow, thanks a lot!!

It would be interesting to have a reference to an R code for the "bootstrap on the difference of medians", or to see an R code, since the procedure on that link is not super clear...

See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51481772/how-to-perform-a-bootstrap-and-find-95-confidence-interval-for-the-median-of-a   Or this https://rcompanion.org/handbook/E_04.html

This would be a comment, but it is probably too long to be written in the comments section. However, it is strongly related to the @jginestet's answer.
I tried to perform, with R, the procedure described in the Bootstrapping Two Medians article, kindly suggested by @jginestet, who I thank! To the best of my knowledge, there is not any $p-$ value involved or calculated in this method (so far I did not find any reference on books about the Bootstrapping Two Medians method, except the article kindly suggested by @jginestet):
# Function
bootstrap_medians <- function(sample1, sample2, num_bootstraps = 10000) {
  # Bootstrap each sample separately
  bootstrapped_medians1 <- numeric(num_bootstraps)
  bootstrapped_medians2 <- numeric(num_bootstraps)
  for (i in 1:num_bootstraps) {
    bootstrapped_medians1[i] <- median(sample(sample1, length(sample1), replace = TRUE))
    bootstrapped_medians2[i] <- median(sample(sample2, length(sample2), replace = TRUE))
  }
  # Calculate the differences between the medians
  median_differences <- bootstrapped_medians1 - bootstrapped_medians2
  # Calculate the confidence interval, i.e. check if zero is included 
  # or not in the confidence interval
  CI <- quantile(median_differences, probs = c(0.025, 0.975))
  if (any(0 >= CI[1] & 0 <= CI[2])) {
    H <- 0
    print('We fail to reject the null hypothesis that there is no difference between the medians.')
  } else {
    H <- 1
    print('We reject the null hypothesis that there is no difference between the medians.')
  }
  return(list(H = H, CI = CI))
}

# Example
set.seed(123) # For reproducibility
sample1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2)
sample2 <- rnorm(100, mean = 12, sd = 3)
result <- bootstrap_medians(sample1, sample2)
print(result)

Result:
[1] "We reject the null hypothesis that there is no difference between the medians."
> print(result)
$H
[1] 1

$CI
      2.5%      97.5% 
-2.2811594 -0.5570335 

This result can be compared to the Mood's median test, still kindly suggested by @jginestet:
> mood_test <- mood.test(sample1, sample2)
> print(mood_test)

which results in:
    Mood two-sample test of scale

data:  sample1 and sample2
Z = -2.8343, p-value = 0.004593
alternative hypothesis: two.sided

The very low $p-$value of the Mood two-sample test of scale is in agreement with the "reject the null hypothesis" result from the Bootstrapping Two Medians method, i.e. the two medians, in this example, are statistically different.

However, as we can see in the following three examples, the two tests are not always in agreement. This would trigger a further question: what is the most reliable test?
Example 1: the two tests are in agreement
> set.seed(123) # For reproducibility
> sample1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2)
> sample2 <- rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2)
> # Bootstrap's median test
> result <- bootstrap_medians(sample1, sample2)
[1] "We fail to reject the null hypothesis that there is no difference between the medians."
> print(result)
$H
[1] 0

$CI
      2.5%      97.5% 
-0.2777713  1.1192603 

> # Mood's median test
> mood_test <- mood.test(sample1, sample2)
> print(mood_test)

    Mood two-sample test of scale

data:  sample1 and sample2
Z = -0.33994, p-value = 0.7339
alternative hypothesis: two.sided

Example 2: the two tests disagree
> set.seed(123) # For reproducibility
> sample1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2)
> sample2 <- rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 3)
> # Bootstrap's median test
> result <- bootstrap_medians(sample1, sample2)
[1] "We fail to reject the null hypothesis that there is no difference between the medians."
> print(result)
$H
[1] 0

$CI
      2.5%      97.5% 
-0.2811594  1.4429665 

> # Mood's median test
> mood_test <- mood.test(sample1, sample2)
> print(mood_test)

    Mood two-sample test of scale

data:  sample1 and sample2
Z = -3.5578, p-value = 0.000374
alternative hypothesis: two.sided

Example 3: the two tests are in agreement
> set.seed(123) # For reproducibility
> sample1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2)
> sample2 <- rnorm(100, mean = 11, sd = 2)
> # Bootstrap's median test
> result <- bootstrap_medians(sample1, sample2)
[1] "We fail to reject the null hypothesis that there is no difference between the medians."
> print(result)
$H
[1] 0

$CI
      2.5%      97.5% 
-1.2777713  0.1192603 

> # Mood's median test
> mood_test <- mood.test(sample1, sample2)
> print(mood_test)

    Mood two-sample test of scale

data:  sample1 and sample2
Z = 0.10779, p-value = 0.9142
alternative hypothesis: two.sided


The bootstrap method does not give you a p-value, but instead gives you a CI (which you can interpret as the inverse of a p-value, even though this is not hopw the bootstrap method computes it: the CI is the ensemble of all parameters (in your case, median) for which the p-value would be $<\alpha$. The fact that they can disagree should not be a huge surprise, as they use very different methods. Moreover, bootstrap is very dependent on how representative your samples are.
